# Ejabberd : Creating Custom Authentication with Webservice

Tags: web-services, xmpp, ejabberd

Is it possible to create custom authentication on Ejabberd with .NET Webservice?  I want to override the default authentication happening on Ejabberd.  The version I would be using on Ejabberd would be the latest available.

Any pointers / help regarding this is appreciable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External authentication is fully possible. We used it for a while to authenticate our users against a Rails application, but then had a little to much instability and had to create our own module.

The great advantage with components is that you can write them in any language as long as they [implement the API described here](http://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd/trunk/doc/dev.html#htoc9).

Your own module, on the other hand will have to be in Erlang... which is not as tough as it seems but still a pretty big investment if you have never worked with Erlang.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be possible.

Do you have any specific problems with the C# example on http://www.ejabberd.im/extauth?

All you have to do is make a Console Application that prints out 21 or 20 depending whether it was a success or failure.